# Data in RecycleCiew from Sql database only updates after i restart the app

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am making a feature for my app where the user can add a new food item inside RecyleView. But instead using a new activity I opted out for a popup that appears in the Main Activity where you can enter the food and the price which means the activity doesn't refresh. How can I display the items in the RecycleView without restarting the app?

Code in Main Activity:

```
public class SecondScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_screen);

myDB = new MyDataBaseHelper(SecondScreen.this);
foodID = new ArrayList<>();
foodName = new ArrayList<>();
foodPrice = new ArrayList<>();

 popUp();

//Data from Sql Tables
storeDataInArrays();
customAdapater = new CustomAdapater(SecondScreen.this, foodID, foodName, foodPrice);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SecondScreen.this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapater);

//Storing the data from the sql table
     public void storeDataInArrays(){
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        //Gets the count of the rows
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                foodID.add(cursor.getString(0));
                foodName.add(cursor.getString(1));
                foodPrice.add(cursor.getString(2));
            }
        }
     }
}

public void PopUP(){
btnAddFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDataBaseHelper myDB = new MyDataBaseHelper(SecondScreen.this);
           myDB.addFood(edtFoodName.getText().toString().trim(),
           edtFoodPrice.getText().toString().trim());
           
           //Dismisses the popUp after button click
           myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

}

}
```

Code for RecycleView Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapater.MyViewHolder> {

     Context context;
     private ArrayList foodID, foodName, foodPrice;
     CheckBox chkItem;

    //Constructor
    CustomAdapater(Context context, ArrayList foodID, ArrayList foodName, ArrayList foodPrice){

        //Declares to global variables that can be used in the MainAcivity
       this.context = context;
       this.foodID = foodID;
       this.foodName = foodName;
       this.foodPrice = foodPrice;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomAdapater.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflates the item_row layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapater.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.checkItem.setText(String.valueOf(foodName.get(position)));
        holder.foodPrice_txt.setText(String.valueOf(foodPrice.get(position) + "$"));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodID.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView foodPrice_txt;
        CheckBox checkItem;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            checkItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkItemRow);
            foodPrice_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPriceRow);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [`notifyItemInserted`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)) after adding the item to your database and array lists, to update your adapter.

Like so:

```
String foodName = edtFoodName.getText().toString().trim();
String foodPrice = edtFoodPrice.getText().toString().trim();

myDB.addFood(foodName, foodPrice);

foodNames.add(foodName);
foodPrices.add(foodPrice);

customAdapater.notifyItemInserted(foodNames.size() - 1);
```

Comment: I added the notifyItemInserted fucntion for my adapter in btnAddFood.setOnClickListener in my MainAcitivity but it doesn't update the RecyleView after its pressed. I also tried notifyDataSetChanged() function but still nothing. Am i doing something wrong?